# Передать данные из Popup в НЕвызывающую Активити. Как грамотно организовать?

Tags: java, android

Есть Activity0, в которой создается обьект созданного мной класса (ToggleValues). Этот обьект настраивает всплывающее окно с EditText, кнопками OK и CANCEL, и запускает его. По событию OnClick кнопки OK нужно данные в EditText передать в Activity0.
С этим у меня не возникло бы затруднений, если бы фактическое создание Popup я не вынес в отдельный класс ToggleValues. Подсмотрел такое где-то, и мне понравилось. Но теперь, создавая слушателя в Activity0 для назначения его на кнопку OK в другом классе, я имею ситуацию которая меня запутала. Слушатель должен быть статическим, и данные я в Activity0 использовать не могу.
Не уверен что внятно обьяснил, если что дополню кодом.

Сделав несколько переменных в Activity0 статическими, мне удалось работать с полученными данными. Только не могу из статического слушателя в Activity0 закрыть Activity0. А надо.

Чувствую что ерунду сделал. Подскажите как сделать правильно?

Comment: правильно будет добавить связанный с проблемой код в вопрос. из этих словесных описаний мало что понятно. так же элементы жизненного цикла, как активити, не должны иметь никакой статики по хорошему. классическое решение с передачей чего бы то ни было куда бы то ни было по событию (у вас нажатие кнопки) - коллбэк (интерфейс обратного вызова)

Comment: *"Слушатель должен быть статическим"* - это по заданию или вы сами так решили? Слушатель может быть каким угодно - главное чтобы ссылка на активность (явная или неявная) не пережила жизненный цикл этой активности.

Comment: Callback! Спасибо, думаю, то что надо.

Comment: На данный момент решил задачу просто добавив в код Activity0 статический обьект instance типа Activity0. И в Popup через instance обращаюсь к обьектам Activity0. 

Да, instance в этом случае статический. И это не страшно, как я понимаю. Ведь пока существует этот Popup, должен существовоть и Activity0